# Unable to add/import WSO2 JAX-RS service into StratosLive Application Server

Tags: wso2

I have a WSO2 Application Server, version 5.0.1 installed on my local machine.

I created a JAX-RS service and tested it locally.

The WAR file was built and deployed to the local Application Server successfully. When I log in to the local Application server Admin console, I see it displayed under Applications as type JaxWebApp with 'Find Services' listed under the Actions column.

I have a StratosLive subscription and I am trying to ADD/UPLOAD this JAX-RS service as a WAR file to the StratosLive Application Server. The Admin Console for the StratosLive Application Server is different. On the Main tab, It displays Web Applications and Web Services rather than the Applications and Services on the Admin console for the 5.0.1 Application Server I am running locally.

Consequently, I do not see an option to ADD/UPLOAD my JAX-RS service as a WAR file. The only option is to add a Web Application WAR file (I tried this and it does not work properly - thinks it's a web app) or JAX-WS Web Service as a annotated JAR file.

It looks like the StratosLive Application Server I am using may be a different version (earlier maybe) than the 5.0.1 I am using locally.

Has anyone else been able to ADD/UPLOAD a JAX-RS service to a StratosLive Application Server?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it takes small time to upgrade StratosLive version of a product to latest standalone product version. Now StratosLive has been upgraded to latest Application Server version and you should able to run above use case on StratosLive without any issue.